# String search in C# somewhat similiar to LIKE operator in say VB

Tags: c#, string, string-matching

I am aware this question as been asked. And I am not really looking for a function to do so. I was hoping to get some tips on making a little method I made better. Basically, take a long string, and search for a smaller string inside of it. I am aware that there is literally always a million ways to do things better, and that is what brought me here.

Please take a look at the code snippet, and let me know what you think. No, its not very complex, yes it does work for my needs, but I am more interested in learning where the pain points would be using this for something I would assume it would work for, but would not for such and such reason. I hope that makes sense. But to give this question a way to be answered for SO, is this a strong way to perform this task (I somewhat know the answer :) )

Super interested in constructive criticism, not just in "that's bad". I implore you do elaborate on such a thought so I can get the most out of the responses.

```
public static Boolean FindTextInString(string strTextToSearch, string strTextToLookFor)
{
    //put the string to search into lower case
    string strTextToSearchLower = strTextToSearch.ToLower(); 
    //put the text to look for to lower case
    string strTextToLookForLower = strTextToLookFor.ToLower(); 

    //get the length of both of the strings
    int intTextToLookForLength = strTextToLookForLower.Length; 
    int intTextToSearch = strTextToSearchLower.Length;

    //loop through the division amount so we can check each part of the search text
    for(int i = 0; i < intTextToSearch; i++) 
    {
        //substring at multiple positions and see if it can be found
        if (strTextToSearchLower.Substring(i,intTextToLookForLength) == strTextToLookForLower) 
        {
            //return true if we found a matching string within the search in text
            return true; 
        }
    }

    //otherwise we will return false
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Give some sample data please and the expected result.

Comment: I think the code review site is what you're looking for

Comment: Look at the [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator). There is more to it than just a simple `FindTextInString`. However, if you are just looking to "FindTextInString", it does the job, but using `string.Contains` would be better.

Comment: A close match would be using regex which offers the same functionalities, with some syntax differences.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 oh man you weren't kidding, like is wild! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Contains, IndexOf, Regex

Comment: Or, `.Split(...).Length > 1` (seriously dont do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care about finding a substring inside a string, just use `String.Contains()`

Example:

```
string string_to_search = "the cat jumped onto the table";
string string_to_find = "jumped onto";

return string_to_search.ToLower().Contains(string_to_find.ToLower());
```

Comment: Will mark it for sure, I should have specified ignoring .contains. I guess I really would have wanted to know, would this be how .contains handles it?

Comment: @MikeCMR Check this: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2172

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Nice reference.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Ah sweet, thats great!. Will be looking at that often.

Comment: @MikeCMR After referring to Xiaoy312's link, it appears `.Contains` just calls `.IndexOf`

Comment: @MikeCMR it would surprise me if this is how Contains (so IndexOf) would implement is. The Substring call creates a copy of that part of the string and this is not needed since you can implement the check directly on the TextToSearch string without copying anything. Keep in mind behind the scenes strings are just arrays of characters.

Comment: @Knoop, so does sub string make a copy because of immutable vs mutable? so technically, the post really could be a memory kill (what I posted)?

Comment: @MikeCMR no that has nothing to do with immutability. I won't go into too much detail but Substring creates an entirely new string (though that string is a copy of a part of the source string). In the same way you could skip the ToLower() calls since they also create a new string.

Comment: To expand a bit (was traveling during the previous answer). Immutability makes it impossible for Substring() to function any other way but even if it would be possible we wouldn't want it another way. As for the memory kill that's not a problem. Every time the Substring() is called the previous copy is already out of scope so its memory can be reused. It's just that it's quite inefficient to keep copying characters around for the new strings

Comment: @Knoop hey appreciate all that insight, you guys gave worlds of good feedback :). Thanks again! So when you reference inefficiency, are we talking like physical time, or cpu load, or..?

Comment: @MikeCMR Since the cpu needs to do more work (creqting copies of substrings everytime the loop os excecuted) it will indeed take longer then more efficient implementations. But optimization is a complete field on it own and depends on a multitude of factors so it's impossible to explain everything going on (also I myself know only a fraction of the things playing in the background that can impact performance)

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse VB's `Like` operator this way:

1) Make a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` library.

2) Use the following code.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

if (LikeOperator.LikeString(Source: "11", Pattern: "11*", CompareOption: CompareMethod.Text)
{
    // Your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement your function in a case-insensitive way, it may be more appropriate to use `IndexOf` instead of the combination of two `ToLower()` calls with `Contains`. This is both because `ToLower()` will generate a new string, and because of [the Turkish İ Problem](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

Something like the following should do the trick, where it returns `False` if either term is `null`, otherwise uses a case-insensitive `IndexOf` call to determine if the search term exists in the source string:

```
public static bool SourceContainsSearch(string source, string search)
{
    return search != null &&
           source?.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
}
```